# Why am I getting repeated values in the following JavaScript operation?

Tags: javascript

I have an object with names of days in a week as keys whose values are an array of objects with information about opening and closing time in different shifts.

```
let openingTimes = 
{
    sunday: [
        { id: 1, shift: 'morning', opening_time: '07:00', closing_time: '11:00' },
        { id: 1, shift: 'day',    opening_time: '13:30', closing_time: '16:30' },
        { id: 1, shift: 'night', opening_time: '20:00', closing_time: '23:00' }
    ],
    monday: [
        { id: 1, shift: 'day',    opening_time: '13:30', closing_time: '16:30' }
    ],
    wednesday: [
        { id: 1, shift: 'morning', opening_time: '07:00', closing_time: '12:00' },
        { id: 1, shift: 'night', opening_time: '20:00', closing_time: '23:00' }
    ],
    thursday: [
        { id: 1, shift: 'morning', opening_time: '07:00', closing_time: '12:00' },
        { id: 1, shift: 'night', opening_time: '20:00', closing_time: '23:00' }
    ],
    friday: [
        { id: 1, shift: 'day',    opening_time: '13:30', closing_time: '16:30' },
        { id: 1, shift: 'night', opening_time: '20:00', closing_time: '23:00' }
    ],
};
```

I'm trying to make a small change in the JSON data. For values of the name of days, I'm trying to add objects whose keys are the shifts and values are the array of time from starting time to closing time with difference of 15 minutes in between them.

[image]

While I did succeed in building the list, I'm unable to figure out why I'm getting exactly the same values for all the days. I'm missing something simple somewhere.

[image]

Here's my code.

```
let Object1 = {};
let Object2 = {};

for (let key in openingTimes)
{
    openingTimes[key].forEach(item =>
    {
         /* Separate opening time to parts by colon */
        let oParts = item.opening_time.split(':');
        let oHour = oParts[0];
        let oMins = oParts[1];

        /* Separate closing time to parts by colon */
        let cParts = item.closing_time.split(':');
        let cHour = cParts[0];
        let cMins = cParts[1];

        Object1[item.shift] = buildTimeArray(oHour, oMins, cHour, cMins, 15);

        Object2[key] = Object1;
    });
}

console.log(Object2);

/**
 * Gather restaurant hours and return the array of available delivery times in difference of specified minutes
 * @params  Opening Hour, Opening Minutes, Closing Hour, Closing Minutes, Miutes Interval
 */
function buildTimeArray(oHour, oMins, cHour, cMins, interval_mins)
{
    let result = [];
    let start = new Date('','','',oHour, oMins);
    let end = new Date('','','',cHour, cMins);
    for (let d = start; d <= end; d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + interval_mins))
    {
        result.push(this.meridianTime(d));
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Build time in 12 hrs AM/PM format
 */
function meridianTime(inputDate)
{
    let hours = inputDate.getHours();
    let minutes = inputDate.getMinutes();
    let ampm = hours < 12 ? "AM" : (hours = hours % 12, "PM");

    hours =  hours === 0 ? 12 : hours < 10? ("0" + hours) : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? ("0" + minutes) : minutes;
    return hours + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm;
}
```

Comment: Initialize `Object1` to `{}` as the first statement in the `for (let key...` loop.

Comment: Also, consider using a date-time library (like Date.js) to reduce all your splitting/ternary operations to a few simple parses and toStrings.

Comment: Good info, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, so you are effectively adding the same object each time.

```js
let openingTimes = {
  sunday: [{
      id: 1,
      shift: 'morning',
      opening_time: '07:00',
      closing_time: '11:00'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      shift: 'day',
      opening_time: '13:30',
      closing_time: '16:30'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      shift: 'night',
      opening_time: '20:00',
      closing_time: '23:00'
    }
  ],
  monday: [{
    id: 1,
    shift: 'day',
    opening_time: '13:30',
    closing_time: '16:30'
  }],
  wednesday: [{
      id: 1,
      shift: 'morning',
      opening_time: '07:00',
      closing_time: '12:00'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      shift: 'night',
      opening_time: '20:00',
      closing_time: '23:00'
    }
  ],
  thursday: [{
      id: 1,
      shift: 'morning',
      opening_time: '07:00',
      closing_time: '12:00'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      shift: 'night',
      opening_time: '20:00',
      closing_time: '23:00'
    }
  ],
  friday: [{
      id: 1,
      shift: 'day',
      opening_time: '13:30',
      closing_time: '16:30'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      shift: 'night',
      opening_time: '20:00',
      closing_time: '23:00'
    }
  ],
};

let Object2 = {};

for (let key in openingTimes) {

  let Object1 = {};

  openingTimes[key].forEach(item => {
    /* Separate opening time to parts by colon */
    let oParts = item.opening_time.split(':');
    let oHour = oParts[0];
    let oMins = oParts[1];

    /* Separate closing time to parts by colon */
    let cParts = item.closing_time.split(':');
    let cHour = cParts[0];
    let cMins = cParts[1];

    Object1[item.shift] = buildTimeArray(oHour, oMins, cHour, cMins, 15);

    Object2[key] = Object1;
  });
}
console.log(Object2);


/**
 * Gather restaurant hours and return the array of available delivery times in difference of specified minutes
 * @params  Opening Hour, Opening Minutes, Closing Hour, Closing Minutes, Miutes Interval
 */
function buildTimeArray(oHour, oMins, cHour, cMins, interval_mins) {
  let result = [];
  let start = new Date('', '', '', oHour, oMins);
  let end = new Date('', '', '', cHour, cMins);
  for (let d = start; d <= end; d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + interval_mins)) {
    result.push(this.meridianTime(d));
  }
  return result;
}

/**
 * Build time in 12 hrs AM/PM format
 */
function meridianTime(inputDate) {
  let hours = inputDate.getHours();
  let minutes = inputDate.getMinutes();
  let ampm = hours < 12 ? "AM" : (hours = hours % 12, "PM");

  hours = hours === 0 ? 12 : hours < 10 ? ("0" + hours) : hours;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? ("0" + minutes) : minutes;
  return hours + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a more functional approach.

When you have a list of data that you need to transform to another list of data, I'm of the opinion that `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` are the way to go.

[This is a decent video that explains the idea](https://youtu.be/e-5obm1G_FY)

Hope this was interesting.

```js
let openingTimes = {
  sunday: [{
      id: 1,
      shift: 'morning',
      opening_time: '07:00',
      closing_time: '11:00'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      shift: 'day',
      opening_time: '13:30',
      closing_time: '16:30'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      shift: 'night',
      opening_time: '20:00',
      closing_time: '23:00'
    }
  ],
  monday: [{
    id: 1,
    shift: 'day',
    opening_time: '13:30',
    closing_time: '16:30'
  }],
  wednesday: [{
      id: 1,
      shift: 'morning',
      opening_time: '07:00',
      closing_time: '12:00'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      shift: 'night',
      opening_time: '20:00',
      closing_time: '23:00'
    }
  ],
  thursday: [{
      id: 1,
      shift: 'morning',
      opening_time: '07:00',
      closing_time: '12:00'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      shift: 'night',
      opening_time: '20:00',
      closing_time: '23:00'
    }
  ],
  friday: [{
      id: 1,
      shift: 'day',
      opening_time: '13:30',
      closing_time: '16:30'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      shift: 'night',
      opening_time: '20:00',
      closing_time: '23:00'
    }
  ],
};

const fifteenMinutes = new Date('1970-01-01 00:15:00') - new Date('1970-01-01 00:00:00');

// notice the single assignment and no for-loops
const transformedOpeningTimes = (Object
  // grab the keys
  .keys(openingTimes)
  // map to tuples of key values
  .map(dayOfTheWeek => ({
    dayOfTheWeek,
    times: openingTimes[dayOfTheWeek]
  }))
  // map the values to `shifts`
  .map(({
    dayOfTheWeek,
    times
  }) => ({
    dayOfTheWeek,
    // for each time, reduce into the `shifts` object
    shifts: times.reduce((shifts, time) => {
      const {
        opening_time,
        closing_time,
        shift
      } = time;
      const lower = new Date(`1970-01-01 ${opening_time}`).getTime();
      const upper = new Date(`1970-01-01 ${closing_time}`).getTime();
      // calculate how many interval we need
      const intervals = parseInt((upper - lower) / fifteenMinutes);
      shifts[shift] = (Array(intervals)
        // create an array with the same length of intervals
        .fill(0)
        // map them to dates
        .map((_, index) => new Date(index * fifteenMinutes + lower))
        // map the dates to time strings
        .map(date => date.toTimeString())
        // convert the time strings to other time strings
        .map(dateString => {
          const hours = parseInt(dateString.slice(0, 2));
          const amOrPm = hours > 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
          return `${hours % 12}:${dateString.slice(3, 5)} ${amOrPm}`;
        })
      );
      return shifts;
    }, {})
  }))
  // reduce back into the object
  .reduce((transformedOpeningTimes, {
    dayOfTheWeek,
    shifts
  }) => {
    transformedOpeningTimes[dayOfTheWeek] = shifts;
    return transformedOpeningTimes;
  }, {})
);

console.log(transformedOpeningTimes);
```